# Rxjs: Recursive Http calls based on condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I retrieve a list using the following command by giving a fixed number of record. In the folowing example, it returns 100 records (I pass the `pageIndex` value and it should be increased in every request in order to get the next 100 record):

```
this.employeeService.list(1, 100).toPromise().then(data => {
    this.employees = data.items;
});
```

There is a flag in the data called `isComplete` and I want to make the same `Http` call to the same list method if the `data.isComplete` value is `false`. What is a proper approach to perform this using `Rxjs` in `Angular`? There are some approaches e.g. recursive subscription etc, but not seems to be good for this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A Possible Solution:

You probably want expand and reduce:

I'm assuming page index starts at 0, the page index that you start with before 'expand' must be 1 less than the first page index from your service.

```js
of({
  isComplete: false,
  pageIndex: -1,
  items: []
}).pipe(
  expand(data => this.employeeService.list(data.pageIndex+1, 100).pipe(
    map(newData => ({...newData, pageIndex: data.pageIndex+1}))
  )),
  takeWhile(data => !(data.isComplete === true), true),
  map(data => data.items),
  reduce((acc, items) => ([...acc, ...items]))
).subscribe(res => {
  this.employees = res;
});
```

#### A quick aside about promises:

`observableStream.toPromise().then(LAMBDA);`

is roughly equivalent to

`observableStream.pipe(last()).subscribe(LAMBDA);`

`last` waits for the source to compete and only emits the final value. This drops all other values in the stream.

many people who first work with Observables and Promises tend to assume it works more like:

`observableStream.pipe(first()).subscribe(LAMBDA);`

so that it takes the first value, then resolves the Promise with that value ASAP. This is, in fact, not the case.

---

In general, it is wise to stick with one or the other. Observable are a super-set of Promises. Short of third-party libraries expecting promises, there should never be a **need** to convert an Observable to Promise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and inform you about the result. Should I use `toPromise()` or `subscribe` in order to fill dropdownlists (for this example and for other situation, filling all of them at once)?

Comment: In general, mixing observable and promises is a code smell. Unless you're using a library that requires/returns one or the other, I wouldn't convert between the two.

Comment: I tried your method but `reduce((acc, items) => ([...acc, ...items]))` line throws *"core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: items is not iterable"* error. Any idea?

Comment: I assumed items was an array, I can't look/advice on anything more than what you've written/shown in your question. Just modify the code to suit your needs :)

Comment: What about using a pegeIndex in order to retrieve the data in the next 100 record? I updated the method in my question. Should I increase the pageIndex value and then accumulate each time the returned value?

Comment: Could you please update your answer for this pageIndex situation? And if it is possible it may be more easier for me who are new in RxJs :)

Comment: I added in a page index into expand, though that doesn't fix your `items is not iterable` error as I still don't know what `data.items` **is**. Also, `reduce` is what does the work of *"accumulate each time the returned value"*

Comment: **You rock!..** It works like a charm and the error seesm to be caused by setting `isComplete` value wrongly at the first step. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[expand](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/expand) operator is what you're looking for. Example:

```
this.employeeService.list(100).pipe(
    expand((data) => {
        if(data.isComplete) {
            return of(EMPTY);
        } else {
            return this.employeeService.list(100);
        }
    })
).subscribe((data) => {
    //your logic here
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and inform you about the result. Should I use `toPromise()` or `subscribe` in order to fill dropdownlists (for this example and for other situation, filling all of them at once)?

Comment: By the way, for now voted up of course ;)

Comment: @Jonathan Observables are much more powerful than promises. Depending on your use-case, just use the one you're comfortable with. For me, it's observables :-)

Comment: Your solution is simple and easy to use. However, I think we need to make some modification in order to make it work. **1)** I have a `pageIndex` parameter in `employeeService.list(...)` method. I think first I set it its initial value 1 and then increase it for each loop. **2)** I think we need to accumulate returned value in teh subscribe. But I am not sure what is the best way for this. Any idea? Maybe spreading, etc.

Comment: I also updated the method by adding `pageIndex paraeter`.