# How to make recursive HTTP calls using RxJs operators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, rxjs

I use the following method in odder to retrieve data by passing `pageIndex` (1) and `pageSize` (500) for each HTTP call.

```
this.demoService.geList(1, 500).subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data.items;
});
```

The response has a property called `isMore` and I want to modify my method in odder to continue HTTP calls if `isMore` is true. I also need to merge the returned values and finally return the accumulated values.

For example, assuming that there are 5000 records and until 10th HTTP call, the service returns true for `isMore` value. After 10th HTTP call, it returns false and then this method sets `this.data` value with the merged 5000 records. For this problem, should I use `mergeMap` or `expand` or another `RxJs` operator? What is the proper way to solve this problem?

***Update:*** I use the following approach, but it does not merge the returned values and not increase the pageIndex. For this reason it does not work (I tried to make some changes, but could not make it work).

```
let pageIndex = 0;
this.demoService.geList(pageIndex+1, 500).pipe(
    expand((data) => {
        if(data.isComplete) {
            return of(EMPTY);
        } else {
            return this.demoService.geList(pageIndex+1, 500);
        }
    })
).subscribe((data) => {
    //your logic here
});
```

***Update II:***

```
of({
    isMore : true,
    pageIndex: 0,
    items: []
  }).pipe(
    expand(data => demoService.geList(data.pageIndex+1, 100)
    .pipe(
      map(newData => ({...newData, pageIndex: data.pageIndex+1}))
    )),
    // takeWhile(data => data.isMore), //when using this, it does not work if the total record is less than 100
    takeWhile(data => (data.isMore || data.pageIndex === 1)), // when using this, it causing +1 extra HTTP call unnecessarily
    map(data => data.items),
    reduce((acc, items) => ([...acc, ...items]))
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
  });
```

***Update III:***

Finally I made it work by modifying Elisseo's approach as shown below. Howeveri **I need to make it void and set `this.data` parameter in this `getData()` method. How can I do this?

```
getData(pageIndex, pageSize) {
  return this.demoService.geList(pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(
    switchMap((data: any) => {
      if (data.isMore) {
        return this.getData(pageIndex+1, pageSize).pipe(
          map((res: any) => ({ items: [...data.items, ...res.items] }))
        );
      }
      return of(data);
    })
  );
}
```

I want to merge the following subscribe part to this approach but I cannot due to some errors e.g. "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'void'."

```
.subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.data = res;
});
```

Comment: I just need to accumulate returned values after recursive HTTP call. I think it is a general situation for paging or recursive needs. Any help please?

Comment: I hope **RxJs** and **JavaScript** Gurus see this problem and give a proper solution approach :)

Comment: if you use pagination, shouldn't you get the data after an event occurs for example pageIndex changed? why are you trying to get every data if your approach is pagination? if you want to get every data why you're set upper bound to get the data? Couldn't understand the logic you're trying to achieve .

Comment: Thanks amigo. Actually this method is used for pagination and called click next / prev button, you are right. But besides this, I also need to get records by checking the `isMore` value of the response, because giving a fixed number would not solve the problem as the records increase in the future.

Comment: In this example do not think pagination, just think that we need a recursive call by using the page number starting from 1 and then check the `isMore` value of the response. If it is true, continue to recursive call and merge it the previous result. If false, just return the records in the first response.

Comment: How important is the use of recursion for you? Or would you accept any answer that calls an endpoint repeatedly until a condition is met?

Comment: i can understand the flag to give error if trying to click next page but there isn't such any record. I'm assuming you're holding this record in state , can't you just change the data in state like pageData(in page 1 your data will be 1to500), after changing page to 2 you will make another apiCall and get 500 to 1000 and change the paginationData in state and display them ?

Comment: @katzenhut Actually I am looking a proper solution, but if the solution is use a proper approach, it would be ok for me. As far as I see, I need to use `expand()` or something like `merge()` operator of `RxJs`. Could you please post your suggestion so that I can have a try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TalhaAkca Yes Talha, something as you mentioned. At first step, page 1, get the records between 1-500, page 2 501-1000, ... Finally, at page 10 get 4501-5000 and the isMore value is returned as false at this step. By using this thne next call will not be executed and the merged result is returned (or `this.data` value is set with this merged list).

Comment: So @Max load your page in the first state which is 1 to 500, you're dispatching an action 
``` getPaginationData(pageIndex,500)``` you get the data 1to 500. and isMore true as result. You will get the data and equal it to state pageData and your isMore value to state's isMore field. Let's assume your state ``` 
data:data,
isMore: true
 ```

and youre checking to show next button isMore. If it's true you will show next button.After clicking next button you will again dispatch getPaginationData(pageIndex,500) so you don't have to need recursive approach to do that.

Comment: @katzenhut Please see my update and if you fix it that approach would be fine for me.

Comment: @TalhaAkca Please see my update and if you fix it that approach would be fine for me.

Comment: Why not simply loop and increment page number until `isMore` returns false. Each loop set `list = [...list, ...nextPage]` and the page will respond in `*ngFor="let item of list"`. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-recursive-subscription

Comment: Any example please by posting as answer?

Comment: @Benny Could you please see my update and give an answer?

Comment: @max please check my updated comment. If that aproach is cool with you i will post an answer

Comment: @Max see above - I added a link to my KISS example

Comment: @TalhaAkca Sorry, but I could not imagine last part of it. Could you please post your answer so that I can give a try? But be sure that I need to make multiple HTTP calls, because the total record may change.

Comment: @Benny I tried but encounter "Type 'Observable<T>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator." error on `this.list = [...this.list, ...data.list];`

Comment: @Max my simple code is not using Observable. I'm curious how you combined the loop in your code to raise this error

Comment: @Benny Forgot everything and just have a look at my **Update II** please. I added 2 comments regarding the problem wit that approach. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
getData(pageIndex, pageSize) {
    return this.demoService.getList(pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(
      switchMap((data: any) => {
        if (!data.isCompleted) {
          return this.getData(pageIndex+1, pageSize).pipe(
            map((res: any) => ({ data: [...data.data, ...res.data] }))
          );
        }
        return of(data);
      })
    );
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wh8tkf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
NOTE: I updated pasing as argument pageIndex+1 as @mbojko suggest -before I wrote `pageIndex++`

**UPDATE 2**

Using expand operator we need take account that we need feed the "recursive function" with an object with pageIndex -it's necesarry in our call- for this, when we make `this.demoService.getList(data.pageIndex+1,10)` we need "transform the result" adding a new property "pageIndex". for this we use "map"

```
  getData() {
    //see that initial we create "on fly" an object with properties: pageIndex,data and isCompleted
    return of({
      pageIndex:1,
      data:[],
      isCompleted:false
    }).pipe(
      expand((data: any) => {
        return this.demoService.getList(data.pageIndex,10).pipe(
            //here we use map to create "on fly" and object
            map((x:any)=>({
              pageIndex:data.pageIndex+1, //<--pageIndex the pageIndex +1
              data:[...data.data,...x.data], //<--we concatenate the data using spread operator
              isCompleted:x.isCompleted}))  //<--isCompleted the value
        )
      }),
      takeWhile((data: any) => !data.isCompleted,true), //<--a take while
            //IMPORTANT, use "true" to take account the last call also
      map(res=>res.data)  //finally is we only want the "data" 
                          //we use map to return only this property
    )
  }
```

Well we can do a function like this:

```
  getData() {
    of({pageIndex:1,data:[],isCompleted:false}).pipe(
      expand((data: any) => {
        return this.demoService.getList(data.pageIndex,10).pipe(
            tap(x=>{console.log(x)}),
            map((x:any)=>({
              pageIndex:data.pageIndex+1,
              data:[...data.data,...x.data],
              isComplete:x.isComplete}))
        )
      }),
      takeWhile((data: any) => !data.isComplete,true), //<--don't forget the ",true"
    ).subscribe(res=>{
       this.data=res.data
    })
  }
```

See that in this case we don't return else simple subscribe to the function and equal a variable this.data to res.data -it's the reason we don't need the last map

**Update 3** by [Mrk Sef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13500986/mrk-sef)

Finally, if you don't want your stream to emit intermittent values and you just want the final concatenated data, you can remove the data concatenation from `expand`, and use `reduce` afterward instead.

```js
  getData() {
    of({
      pageIndex: 1,
      data: [],
      isCompleted: false
    })
      .pipe(
        expand((prevResponse: any) => this.demoService.getList(prevResponse.pageIndex, 10).pipe(
            map((nextResponse: any) => ({
              ...nextResponse,
              pageIndex: prevResponse.pageIndex + 1
            }))
          )
        ),
        takeWhile((response: any) => !response.isCompleted, true),
        // Keep concatenting each new array (data.items) until the stream
        // completes, then emit them all at once
        reduce((acc: any, data: any) => {
          return [...acc, ...data.data];
        }, [])
      )
      .subscribe(items => {
        this.data=items;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Instead of `pageIndex++; return this.getData(pageIndex, pageSize)`, just `return this.getData(pageIndex + 1, pageSize)`.

Comment: @Eliseo Yes, exactly what I want and it does not send extra HTTP requests. There are 810 records and if I set page size 100, it sends 9 HTTP calls, if the page size is 500, it sends 2 HTTP calls :)

Comment: I needed to make some modifications but finally made it work. On the other hand, how can I make it void and set `this.data` in the getData method instead of onInit?

Comment: By the way I cannot vote up, as I have not enough reputation. Could you pls vote up?

Comment: **On the other hand, how can I make it void and set this.data in the getData method instead of onInit?**

Comment: Max, `getData(pageIndex,pageSize)`return an **Observable** so you need subscribe to this observable to get the data. You can make in the ngOnInit or use in .html using pipe async `<div *ngFor="let item of getData(1,10)|async as data">` see the docs:https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I need to convert getData method so that I move the subscribe part in the method call to this getData method. Something like the esamples on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957969/rxjs-recursive-http-calls-based-on-condition/65959045?noredirect=1#comment116625728_65959045

Comment: @Eliseo Any help please?

Comment: @Max, I update the answer using "expand" operator. Well it's the first time I used "expand", I hope the comments can help you to undersand the operator. I updated the stackblit also. Be Carefull! takeWhile need add the parameter "true" to take account the last value

Comment: Perfect!!! This approach also does not send extra HTTP call, and both of your methods is working like a charm. Many thanks these wonderful approaches. Regards...

Comment: @Max, I just corrected a few the code, changing the "pageIndex", Really I don't like so much the before `getList(data.pageIndex+1,10)` but you need start with 1

Comment: You are right, it is cleaner actually an I also like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MrkSef has updated the question improving using reduce

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if you're total record change as long as api response give you the isMore flag.

I'm skipping the part how to implement reducer action event i'm assuming you've already done that part. So i will just try to explain with pseudo codes.

You have a table or something like that with pagination data. on intial state you can just create an loadModule effect or using this fn:

getPaginationDataWithPageIndex(pageIndex = 1){
this.store.dispatch(new GetPaginationData({ pageIndex: pageIndex, dataSize: 500}));
}

in your GetPaginationData effect

```
... map(action => {
return apicall.pipe(map((response)=> {
   if(response.isMore){
    return new updateState({data:response.data, isMore: responseisMore})
} else {
   return new updateState({isMore: response.isMore}),
}
}})
`

all you have to left is subscribing store in your .ts if isMore is false you will not display the next page button. and on your nextButton or prevButton's click method you should have to just dispatch the action with pageIndex
```

Comment: Forgot everything and just have a look at my **Update II** please. I added 2 comments regarding the problem wit that approach. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks Talha, but I am confused and would be happy if you edit your answer according to the method that use. Update II is better to edit if I fix the extra 1 HTTP call problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I want to vote up your solution, but unfortunately could not as I have no enough reputation. Any vote up for the question please? Regards.

Comment: @Max glad that i can help

Comment: Do you have any idea about my Update III?

Comment: if you wan't to achieve that why are you trying to return an observable ? if you want to make a call and assign the response to local variable why don't you just subscribe? This isn't the best practices in my opinion? if you can provide a stackblitz i can see the big picture. as far as you told this doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think recursion is the correct approach here:

```
interval(0).pipe(
    map(count => this.demoService.getList(count + 1, 500)),
    takeWhile(reponse => response.isMore, true),
    reduce((acc, curr) => //reduce any way you like),
).subscribe();
```

This should make calls to your endpoint until the endpoint returns isMore === false. The beautiful thing about interval is that we get the count variable for free.

But if you are set on using recrsion, here is the rxjs-way to do that using the expand-operator (see the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-expand)). I find it slightly less readable, as it requires an if-else-construct which increases code complexity. Also the outer 'counter' variable just isn't optimal.

```
let index = 1;
this.demoService.geList(index, 500).pipe(
    expand(response => response.isMore ? this.demoService.geList(++index, 500) : empty()),
    reduce((acc, curr) => //reduce here)
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I also tried `takeWhile` before asking the question, but in this case I send an extra 1 HTTP call as I check the condition after call. But maybe in yoru approach the problem not occurs. However, I could not make it work due to `this.processResponse`. In this line I need to merge each result and I do not know should I use HTTP call method instead of `interval(1000)`. Any idea?

Comment: You could also edit teh approach in my Update.

Comment: @Max - I m having trouble picturing this. could you explain what you expect 'data' to be in your subscribe()?

Comment: @Max - have you tried using reduce? https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce

Comment: I expect object array ad data. Reduce may be good option, but why could not you post an answer according to my code in Update section of the question? There is no interval etc in my question.

Comment: Forgot everything and just have a look at my **Update II** please. I added 2 comments regarding the problem wit that approach. Any idea?

Comment: @Max - because, if you want to repeat things in rxjs, interval or similar methods are your best choice. by mapping from the count to the actual request i can easily control when my condition is met, and after that it should be easy to achieve what you want using the correct operators. the problem just gets easier to handle without the recursion, which, in my oopinion, is a good thing. If you are set on a recursive approach, i can try to think of one.

Comment: @Max - try this solution to the takeWhile/ reduce - Problem. Should work the same for recursive and iterative solutions. Basically the second argument to takeWhile will determine whether or not you receive the observable that didnt meet the condition. this lets you get rid of that pesky count problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I want to vote up your solution, but unfortunately could not as I have no enough reputation. Any vote up for the question please? Regards.

Comment: @Max - see edit, this might be more in line with wjhat you want. Also, i can't upvote your question in it's current state, as it (as well as my answer) is a mess. But if you clean it up, i will adjust my answer and i will upvote your question.

Comment: Please see my Update III. By the way, Thanks for your helps, voted up ;)