# How to implement polling in angular to call api until the data is received

Tags: angular

I need to call a API until the status is "Received" then I have to stop the calling,no idea how to implement that:

```js
SendToBank() {
this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`).Subscribe(s=>{
        ////call until s["status"]=="Recieved"
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rxjs: Recursive Http calls based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957969/rxjs-recursive-http-calls-based-on-condition)

Comment: Long story short, use `expand` operator.

Comment: @Antoniossss could you please make an example?i need to get it working with half an hour ,its frustrating

Comment: You have a duplicate link already.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do it. Most rudimentary would be to use a RxJS `timer` with `takenUntil` operator + `Subject` multi-cast to control the subscription.

```js
import { Observable, timer, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

const INTERVAL = 5000;  // <-- poll every 5 seconds

export class someComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  closeTimer$ = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    timer(0, INTERVAL).pipe(      // <-- start immediately and poll every `INTERVAL` seconds
      switchMap(() => this.sendToBank()),  // <-- map to another observable
      takeUntil(this.closeTimer$)   // <-- close the subscription when `closeTimer$` emits
    ).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        if (res["status"]=="Recieved") {
          this.closeTimer$.next();  // <-- stop polling
        }
        // do something else
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        // handle errors
        // note that any errors would stop the polling here
      }
    );
  }

  sendToBank(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stopTimer$.next();    // <-- close the polling anyway when the component is closed
  }
}
```

Comment: If inside ssendBank i need to have another call right after the first polling is finished,to keep calling until the status is "Finalized",what should i do?

Comment: @masali: Do you mean to say that after the `res["status"]=="Recieved"` from the 1st polling, you'd like to start a completely separate polling to another API until it's status is `'Finalized'`?

Comment: the same API actually waiting for QRCode scan from the user,once scan is done,in the back end the status is Fanalized

Comment: @masali: The specifics doesn't help in this context. My question is: are the polling seperate (poll an API till `Received` -> poll another API till `Finalized`) or together (poll an API till `Received` AND another `API` till `Finalized`)?

Comment: they are seperate once the received finished the second polling starts ,the second one should wait for the first one to be finished

Comment: @masali Its in the duplication link - expand will do that for you