# Run method every 5 seconds related on status

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have method in component that getting data from back end and check statuses

Here is it

```
 getRecognitionById() {
    this.loaderService.show(null, true);

    this.vendorWebApiService
      .createRecognition(this.executiveChangeId)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.vendorWebApiService
          .getRecognition(res.taskRequestId, this.executiveChangeId)
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe((recognitionResponse) => {
            if (recognitionResponse.jobStatus === "completed") {
              this.recognitionData = recognitionResponse;
              this.getLatesFeedback();
            }
            if (recognitionResponse.jobStatus === "failed") {
              alert();
            } else {
              
            }
          });
      });
  }
```

In this part I check status

```
 this.vendorWebApiService
      .getRecognition(res.taskRequestId, this.executiveChangeId)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((recognitionResponse) => {
        if (recognitionResponse.jobStatus === "completed") {
          this.recognitionData = recognitionResponse;
          this.getLatesFeedback();
        }
        if (recognitionResponse.jobStatus === "failed") {
          alert();
        } else {

        }
      });
```

But problem that if status is another then complete or failed, I need to rerun this logic again every 5 seconds , so every 5 seconds I need to check status and after 10's try, I need to show alert.

How I need to rewrite my code to achieve this logic?

Comment: it seems like you need to recursively call the api which means you should use the `expand` operator. Also you need to set a `takeUntil`/`takeWhile` based on your `jobStatus` so that you can get out of the loop. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957969/rxjs-recursive-http-calls-based-on-condition/65958250#65958250

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with rxjs

```js
    import { interval, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    refresher$: Observable<number>;
    refreshSub: Subscription;
    jobStatus: string = "init"
    checkCount = 0

    checkStatus() {
      this.checkCount++
      this.vendorWebApiService
        .getRecognition(res.taskRequestId, this.executiveChangeId)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((recognitionResponse) => {
          jobStatus = recognitionResponse.jobStatus
          this.recognitionData = recognitionResponse
          
        });
    }

    getRecognitionById() {
      this.loaderService.show(null, true);

      this.checkStatus()
   }

    this.refresher$ = interval(5000); // every5 sec
    this.refreshSub = this.refresher$.subscribe(() => {
      this.checkStatus()
      if (this.jobStatus === 'completed') {
        this.getLatesFeedback();
      }
      if (this.jobStatus === 'failed') {
        alert()
      } else {
         if (this.checkCount == 10) {
            alert()
         }
      }

    });
```

Comment: I need only to run ` this.vendorWebApiService
          .getRecognition` and status checks, not whole  `getRecognitionById`

Re read post please

Comment: The do a method statusCheck() with the service call, call this statusCheck() method in getRecognitionById, and iside the refreshSub

Comment: Can you provide code, how to do this?

Comment: Edited, is this working for u ?

Comment: As I understood your code correctly, you just run check status every 5 seconds.

Logic I try to achieve, is run `getRecognition` again if status is diffrent from `failed` or `completed`.

And on 10's try if status not completed, show `alert()`

Comment: Observable that fetch from a URL only send the request when they are subscribed to (simple explanation). So yes, this should run your status check against the server every 5 seconds.

Comment: To round out your need, you would need a status counter that iterates each time you check against the server and in your specific case when it reaches the second iteration it should execute the alert if it didn’t succeed.

Comment: I implemented the checkCount here, is it correct now ?

Comment: Also one question, part of answer that contains  `this.refresher$ = interval(5000); // every5 sec
    this.refreshSub = this.refresher$.subscribe(()`

is not related to any method?

Comment: And if status completed, now from your code I think checking status will be reruning.

I need to stop it if it `completed` or `failed` and run again only it has another statuses

Comment: I didnt try it but i think you could this.refreshSub.unsubscribe() in both case completed / failed. That should stop the checking. Also I dont understand the question related to any method :)

Comment: I think now, you have the tools to complete what you are seeking to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that this way:

1. Define a counter variable.
2. Define an interval with a 5000ms timer and reference it to a variable.
3. Clear interval on success.
4. Re-run interval on failure and a counter of `counter < 10`.

```
let counter = 0;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  // ajax().next(() => {
  //   clearInterval(interval);
  // }).catch(() => {
  //   if (counter >= 10) {
  //     clearInterval(interval);
  //   } else {
  //     counter++;
  //   }
  // })
}, 5000);
```

- Do NOT forget to clear your interval in `ngOnDestroy` to prevent your app from crash in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

With observables you could try something like this

```
  getRecognitionById() {
    //   this.loaderService.show(null, true);
    const ATTEMPT_COUNT = 10;
    const DELAY = 5000;
    this.vendorWebApiService
      .createRecognition(this.executiveChangeId)
      .pipe(take(1),
        mergeMap((res) => (
          this.vendorWebApiService
            .getRecognition(res.taskRequestId, this.executiveChangeId)
            .pipe(take(1),
          ))), map((recognitionResponse: any) => {
            if (recognitionResponse.jobStatus === "completed") {
              this.recognitionData = recognitionResponse;
              this.getLatesFeedback();
            }
            if (recognitionResponse.jobStatus === "failed") {
              alert();
            } else {
              throw { error: 'failed' };
            }
          }), retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
            scan((errorCount, err: any) => {
              if (err.error === 'failed' || errorCount >= ATTEMPT_COUNT) {
                // add code for alert after 10 retries
              }
              return errorCount + 1;
            }, 0),
            delay(DELAY),
          )));
  }
```

Comment: got this `Property 'switchmap' does not exist on type`

Comment: and I need to show alert only if status failed, in else block, I need to rerun logic again

Comment: @EugeneSukh  I have updated the code, can you please take this one and let me know